# GraphQL type for generic "Object" type (Java, C#)

Tags: java, object, generics, graphql, c#-3.0

I am trying to port a legacy RESTful api server implementation to GraphQL and there are some controller / service functions which accepts Object as a property of input parameter.

I would like to find out how to translate generic type Object (C#, Java) to GraphQL.

Expected GraphQL to have type definition for generic type Object (C#, Java) and leaves it to the GraphQLResolver to handle it.

Comment: Are you looking for some type that's the root of all other types?  To query against a field that only implements some vague interface?  Trying to get out of writing a schema or resolvers in a server implementation?

Comment: I am trying to port a legacy RESTful api server implementation to GraphQL and there are some controller / service functions which accepts Object as a property of input parameter.