# GraphQL.NET dynamic field type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, graphql-dotnet, graphql.net

I'm trying to add an object to my GraphQL.NET model, but I'm having a problem with one of the fields. The original class is

```
public class ShowCriterion
{
    public string RelatedEntity { get; set; }
    public object MatchValue { get; set; }
}
```

This takes a materialized path (like `Person.Address.ZipCode`), and compares it with the `MatchValue`. Problem is, `MatchValue` can be quite a lot of different things: boolean, int, string, List/array, DateTime, etc.

My first try was to create the GraphQL class as follows:

```
    public partial class ShowCriterionQL : ObjectGraphType<ShowCriterion>
    {
        public ShowCriterionQL()
        {
            Field(x => x.RelatedEntity, type: typeof(StringGraphType));
            Field(x => x.MatchValue, type: typeof(ObjectGraphType));
        }
    }
```

But it gives the following error:

```
GraphQL.Validation.ValidationError: Field matchValue of type ObjectGraphType must have a sub selection
```

If I make it a `StringGraphType` it will convert some values correctly (e.g. boolean true becomes "True"), but I really don't like this solution as it would require special handling on the client side. I also haven't explored all the possible types to see what happens with an array or a DateTime.

Is there any way to do this in GraphQL.NET?

(In searching I found several resources for dealing with type parameters, but that isn't really helpful to what I'm doing, since I use a generic object and use reflection at runtime to determine how to handle a particular value. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276645/graphql-type-for-generic-object-type-java-c) unanswered question which is very similar...but sadly unanswered.)

Comment: It would appear as though you would probably want a [Union Type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AnyScalarGraphType but note that it is not recognized by the graphql clients although the query having it works fine when executed.

AnyScalarGraphType : https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/blob/master/src/GraphQL/Utilities/Federation/AnyScalarGraphType.cs

GraphQL client issue : https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/issues/1705

You can also create a custom scalar type of your own.